# How to Convert the value in DataTable into a string array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a DataTable that contains a single row. I want to convert this DataTable values into a string array such that i can access the column values of that DataTable through the string array index
For example, if my DataTable is as follows

```
|  Name  |  Address  |   Age  |
-------------------------------
|  jim   |    USA    |   23   |
```

I want to store the values in that Datatable into my string array such that **MyStringArray[1]** will give me the value USA.

Thanks in  Advance

Comment: why not take that value and do a Split(' ') on it..? for example `var MystringArray = "jim USA 23".Split(' ');`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Very easy:

```
var stringArr = dataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Where [`DataRow.ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) property is an array of objects containing the values of the row for each columns of the data table.

Comment: ".Select..." was not an option for my datatable control.  I'm using vs 2017 and all current libraries.

Comment: `Select` is an extension method included in LINQ, not in DataTable. Do you have the `using System.Linq;` among the first lines of your file ?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps something like this, assuming that there are many of these rows inside of the datatable and that each row is `row`:

```
List<string[]> MyStringArrays = new List<string[]>();
foreach( var row in datatable.rows )//or similar
{
 MyStringArrays.Add( new string[]{row.Name,row.Address,row.Age.ToString()} );
}
```

You could then access one:

```
MyStringArrays.ElementAt(0)[1]
```

If you use *linqpad*, here is a very simple scenario of your example:

```
class Datatable
{
 public List<data> rows { get; set; }
 public Datatable(){
  rows = new List<data>();
 }
}

class data
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Address { get; set; }
 public int Age { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
 var datatable = new Datatable();
 var r = new data();
 r.Name = "Jim";
 r.Address = "USA";
 r.Age = 23;
 datatable.rows.Add(r);
 List<string[]> MyStringArrays = new List<string[]>();
 foreach( var row in datatable.rows )//or similar
 {
  MyStringArrays.Add( new string[]{row.Name,row.Address,row.Age.ToString()} );
 }
 var s = MyStringArrays.ElementAt(0)[1];
 Console.Write(s);//"USA"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 
            string[] result = new string[table.Columns.Count];
            DataRow dr = table.Rows[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = dr[i].ToString();
            }
            foreach (string str in result)
                Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: This will store the names of the columns, not the contents of the row(s).

Answer (score 4):

If that's all what you want to do, you don't need to convert it into an array. You can just access it as:

```
string myData=yourDataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString();//Gives you USA
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use *System.Data* instead of *System.LINQ*, then you can do something like this.

```
 List<string> BrandsInDataTable = new List<string>();
 DataTable g = Access._ME_G_BrandsInPop(); 
        if (g.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < g.Rows.Count; x++)
                BrandsInDataTable.Add(g.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString()); 
        }
        else return;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private string[] GetPrimaryKeysofTable(string TableName)
    {
        string stsqlCommand = "SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE " +
                              "WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1" +
                              "AND table_name = '" +TableName+ "'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(stsqlCommand, Connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        adapter.Fill(table);

        string[] result = new string[table.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            result[i++] = dr[0].ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```