# Add checkboxes dynamically

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, calendar, dynamically-generated

I have a calender table which consist of a columns named working days which contain entries (1 or 0) 1 representing the working days and 0 representing the holidays. Now when I get the data from database I want to show check boxes with the the holidays as checked and other unchecked . For example if for a month June data returned is 1111100... then first 5 check boxes should be unchecked and then 2 checked and so on for 30 days of June. In my web page, I have 2 text boxes which take year and month as input. When I search the check boxes should appear for that month. Can you tell me the code for this problem.Following code I have tried.

> public void search(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>               try
>               {
>
> ```
>             string cnnString = "Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=leavesystem;Uid=root;Pwd=ashish";
>             MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
>             cnx.Open();
>             string cmdText = "Select WorkingDays from calender where Year = '" + year.Value +"' and Month = '" + month.Value +"' ";
>             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);
>             MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
>             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>             adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
>             string a[] = adapter.Fill(ds);
>
>               int size = a.Length;
>               CheckBox[] cbl = new CheckBox[size];
>                    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
>                       {
>                           cbl[i] = new CheckBox();
>                           cbl[i].Text = a[i].ToString();
>                           this.Form.Controls.Add(cbl[i]);  
>                       } 
>                }}
>         catch (MySqlException ex)
>         {
>
>             string msg = "Insert Error: 'Error ' ";
>             msg += ex.Message;
>             throw new Exception(msg);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Now I am getting errors. First I am not able to get the adapter.fill value in string array a and then the code ahead is not working. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I again updated answer that is tested and suerly works!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you tried updated answer?

Comment: Yes man I did.The code has no error but only 1 check box is shown on the web page.

Comment: I tested it I say that surely your `adapter.Fill(ds)` have only one digit! you can replace it with another `int` variable that its value be 11100111 and see the result.good bye!

Comment: I edited answer again x 100!!!

Comment: here I see programmer laboring!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CheckBoxList` as this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checks" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"/>
```

then in code behind:

```
char[] a=adapter.Fill(ds).ToString().ToCharArray();
ListItem[] items=new ListItem[a.Count()];
int i=0;
foreach (char m in a){
    items[i]=new ListItem(m.ToString());
    if(m=='0')
       items[i].Selected=true;
    else
       items[i].Selected=false;
    checks.Items.Add(items[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use what you said but it says (Int does not contain a definition for count and not extension method count accepting first argument of type int could  be found)

Comment: Did but still the same problem!

Comment: @AshishBatra can you say me what is in `adapter.Fill(ds)`?

Comment: The column(workingDays) value. The value it gets is 1111100111110011111001111100. I want to show checked boxes for 0's and unchecked for 1's

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert your database table into string array like this.

[How to Convert the value in DataTable into a string array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487660/how-to-convert-the-value-in-datatable-into-a-string-array-in-c-sharp)

then write following code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkList" runat="server"/>
```

code behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
   checks.Items.Add(new ListItem(a[i]));
```