# Datatable first row to 2D array C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement Accord Framework Decision Tree.

```
 DataTable data = new DataTable("Mitchell's Tennis Example");
        data.Columns.Add("Day",typeof(String));
        data.Columns.Add("Day", typeof(String));
        data.Columns.Add("Outlook",typeof(String));
        data.Columns.Add("Temperature",typeof(String));
        data.Columns.Add("Humidity",typeof(String));
        data.Columns.Add("Wind",typeof(String));
        data.Columns.Add("PlayTennis",typeof(String));
        data.Rows.Add("D1", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No");
        data.Rows.Add("D2", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No");
        data.Rows.Add("D3", "Overcast", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D4", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D5", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D6", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "No");
        data.Rows.Add("D7", "Overcast", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D8", "Sunny", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "No");
        data.Rows.Add("D9", "Sunny", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D10", "Rain", "Mild", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D11", "Sunny", "Mild", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D12", "Overcast", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D13", "Overcast", "Hot", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        data.Rows.Add("D14", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "No");
        var codebook = new Codification(data);
        DataTable symbols = codebook.Apply(data);
        int[][] inputs = symbols.ToArray<int>("Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind");
        int[] outputs = symbols.ToArray<int>("PlayTennis");
```

The problem is that visual studio gives error on last two lines.

No overload for ToArray takes arguments.

[image: Accord Framework 2D array error.]

I have Visual Studio 2012. Is that visual studio problem or something else?
Using .NET Framework 4.0.
Do I need to change code or install latest visual studio?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104007/copying-data-from-a-table-into-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: To answer your question, you need to change your code. The ToArray method doesn't take any arguments, so it's invalid to put strings as arguments. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487660/how-to-convert-the-value-in-datatable-into-a-string-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.toarray?view=netframework-4.8 Peruse this. As far as I know there isn't an overload for `ToArray()` like you have in your example.

Comment: Thankyou. The code source i am using is from documentation of accord framework. [link](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_DecisionTrees_DecisionTree.htm#!)